# Conocer dirección IP origen con Socket en C

Tags: c, socket, ip

Estoy programando en C y necesito conocer el IP origen de un mensaje, es decir el IP del cliente que se conecte y envíe algo al socket del servidor.

Ej: (-Servidor: Mensaje recibido del cliente con IP: 10.8.1.142)

Este es el código del servidor:

```
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <string.h>
#define PORT 8087

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) { 
    int server_fd, new_socket, valread; 
    struct sockaddr_in address; 
    int opt = 1; 
    int addrlen = sizeof(address); 
    char buffer[1024] = {0}; 

    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) { 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt))) { 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    address.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT ); 

    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address))<0) { 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0) { 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,(socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0) {  
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 1024); 

    printf("Mensaje: %s\n", buffer ); 

    printf("IP Origen: %s\n", ? ); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

---

He probado lo que me dices y no me funciona.

Este es el código:

```
struct in_addr clientIP;
clientIP = address.sin_addr;
char ipStr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
printf("IP Origen: %d\n",inet_ntop(AF_INET, &clientIP, ipStr, INET_ADDRSTRLEN));
```

Esta es la salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando se *acepta* una conexión, recibes un socket que te conecta con el cliente:

```
   new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,(socklen_t*)&addrlen);
// ~~~~~~~~~~                                         ~~~~~~~
// Id socket                                      sockaddr cliente
```

En este caso solo necesitamos `address`. Esta estructura tiene todo lo necesario para conectarnos con el cliente, luego su IP debe estar ahí, en algún lado:

```
struct in_addr clientIp = address.sin_addr;
```

Pero claro, esta estructura tiene la IP *codificada* en binario. Para obtener una representación legible puedes usar la función `inet_ntop`:

```
char ipStr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &clientIP, str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
```

---

En respuesta a la última actualización de la pregunta:

> He probado lo que me dices y no me funciona ...

Citar a lo comentado por @Trauma:

> Te faltan los includes `<sys/types.h>` y `<arpa/inet.h>`. Ello está perfectamente documentado con solo hacer man inet_ntop, o una simple búsqueda en Google

Comment: Solucionado. Muchas gracias por todo !!!